# play! framework or typesafe-stack

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

Playframework now is part of typesafe-stack.

So, what I should download now if I'm going to use scala like main language?

TypsafeStack or PlayFramework2?

As I understand both they use AKKA, STB, etc.

Not very clear. I need some suggestions about that.. What differences between that two ones? It seems they are both a bit more than just web-frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typesafe stack is a bundle of common scala tools, if you happy with standalone play framework and don't use most of the stack tools, just continue usage, but if you are using sbt, g8 and/or akka it's a natural choice to have it all packed together: you install stack and have instruments up and running.

The advantage of Typesafe stack over the just a bunch of components is that it has well tested compability between parts <s>(and that is disadvantage in some sense too: for example you can't use the latest version of sbt 0.12.x until it got all testing done)</s>.

Comment: if download play framework it also works with sbt and akka from box. So not so big difference then. Probably if I need just framework form making the sistes then just plain playframework is ok.

Comment: You *can* use sbt 0.12.x. When you put the 0.12.x version in your `project/build.properties` you'll see the solution after the first run of `sbt`: downloading the right `sbt-launch.jar` and putting it into `~/.sbt/.lib/0.12.0/sbt-launch.jar`